# Why do we need to suppose finite dimension to prove dual of linear map $L$ is injective $\Rightarrow$ $L$ is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Exercise 10.5 from Introduction to manifolds of Tu:

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $K$. Prove that if $L^{\vee}: W^\vee \rightarrow V^\vee $ is injective, then $L$ is surjective. Here $L$ is a linear map $V\rightarrow W$. $V^\vee = Hom(V,K)$ is the dual of $V$. For $f\in W^\vee$, $L^\vee(f)$ is defined as $f\circ L$.

My question is why we suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional. My proof does not need it:

Proof: Let's prove the contraposition. Suppose that $L$ is not surjective, let $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis of $Im(L)$. Complete $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ with $\{b\}\cup \{b_i\}_{i\in J}$ to form a basis of $W$. Consider the linear map $g\in W^\vee$ such that $g(b)=1$ and $g(a_i)=g(b_j)=0$ for all $i\in I$ and $j\in J$. Then $L^\vee (g)=0$, thus $L^\vee$ is not injective.

Comment: First, your proof is correct. Second, have you proved that (a) for any infinite-dimensional space there exists a basis and (b) that you can complete a basis of a subspace of an infinite-dimensional space to a basis of the whole space?

Comment: I suppose I can just use this result. Otherwise use Zorn's lemma to prove it.

Comment: Then it surely works.

Comment: How is it not the same?

Comment: BTW I like your proof. Perhaps finite dimensionality would be needed for a similar statement but with the roles of of injective and surjective flipped? I'm not sure.

Comment: In the book, question a) is "prove $L$ surjective $\Rightarrow$ $L^\vee$ injective", question b) is "suppose $V$, $W$ finite dimensional, prove the converse". So that made me wonder.

Comment: Very weird. Perhaps the authors don't want to get into issues of the type 'does the axiom of choice "really" hold?' and bypass it by staying in the safe grounds of finite dimensionality.